# See retained variance in scikit-learn manifold learning methods

Tags: python, scikit-learn, variance

I have a dataset of images that I would like to run nonlinear dimensionality reduction on. To decide what number of output dimensions to use, I need to be able to find the retained variance (or explained variance, I believe they are similar). Scikit-learn seems to have by far the best selection of manifold learning algorithms, but I can't see any way of getting a retained variance statistic. Is there a part of the scikit-learn API that I'm missing, or simple way to calculate the retained variance?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a clean way to derive the "explained variance" of most non-linear dimensionality techniques, in the same way as it is done for PCA. 
For PCA, it is trivial: you are simply taking the weight of a principal component in the eigendecomposition (i.e. its eigenvalue) and summing the weights of the ones you use for linear dimensionality reduction.
Of course, if you keep all the eigenvectors, then you will have "explained" 100% of the variance (i.e. perfectly reconstructed the covariance matrix).

Now, one could try to define a notion of explained variance in a similar fashion for other techniques, but it might not have the same meaning.
For instance, some dimensionality reduction methods might actively try to push apart more dissimilar points and end up with more variance than what we started with. Or much less if it chooses to cluster some points tightly together.

However, in many non-linear dimensionality reduction techniques, there are other measures that give notions of "goodness-of-fit".
For instance, in scikit-learn, [isomap has a reconstruction error](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.Isomap.html#sklearn.manifold.Isomap.reconstruction_error), [tsne can return its KL-divergence](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html#sklearn.manifold.TSNE), and [MDS can return the reconstruction stress](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.MDS.html#sklearn.manifold.MDS).